# Predicting cucumber harvest

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, prediction

I am trying to predict the harvest of cucumbers in a greenhouse. I have measured data about humidity, temperature, artificial light, sunlight and co2. The amount of cucumbers harvested is per day in kg.
Since a cucumber needs around 14 days to grow, the preceding 14 days of the measured data influence the actual amount of harvested cucumbers on a specific day. I have already created a dataset by associating the average measured data of the preceding 14 days to each harvest result of a given day and trained a prediction model with that. This already gave me promising results.
Now I want to improve the system. Instead of averaging out the preceding 14 days of data and assuming that each day has an influence of 1/14 I want to find out what the actual influence is on the harvest result (a rule of thumb says that the data measured 1 day before harvest has a 50% influence on the actual amount of harvested cucumbers; my goal is to either verify or improve that rule).
 Any idea of how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

There's two methods I thought of depending on which sounds easier to you with your situation:

1) One way you could implement this is by taking performing multiple analyses on different harvests at once.  For example, take three harvests on three consecutive days:

Harvest 1: 12/17/19

Harvest 2: 12/18/19

Harvest 3: 12/19/19

The conditions you recorded on 12/16 would correspond to the last day of Harvest 1, the 12th day of Harvest 2 and the 11th day of Harvest 3.  If your theory is correct that the day before has the greatest impact on harvest yield, the effects of the conditions on 12/16 should be more pronounced on Harvest 1 than the others.

I'm not sure if you wanted a general experimental outline or a procedural statistical/coding approach.  If you are looking for a direction to get started with that, look into multivariate statistical analysis.

2) Another route entirely could go as follows:

Since you've already done experiments on a single set, you might know what conditions are favorable to growth.  If you do and if it's possible to have your neural-network reduce all the conditions on a given day to a single "health" number (good conditions for growth give a higher health number, poor conditions give lower), you could populate a matrix with 14 harvests and the corresponding conditions they saw in terms of your one variable "health" dimension.  From there you could perform regression to determine the weight of each day compared to its effect on growth.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to best predict the cucumber yield for a given day based on the preceding 14 days? Or are you trying to determine which of those preceding 14 days contribute most to the cucumber yield on a given day?

I assume that by stating, "now I want to improve the system", you would like to achieve the former.

Choosing this to be the case, why are you averaging the data recordings for the previous 14 days and not just inputting the actual data for each of the respective 14 days? This way, you could experiment with inputting the last 14 days, then the last 7 days, and maybe even just the last 2 days etc. You are also making no assumptions about the amount of contribution each day has to the yield, but simply that each day does contribute (in the first place). Say you have 5 recordings for each day, and you input all 14 days' worth of information, your neural network would have 5 * 14 = 70 input neurons (the first layer).

You could perhaps even use a recurrent neural network to find a relationship **between** each of the preceding days - maybe increasing accuracy. However, using a neural network in the first place often requires that you have a lot of training data. You might find that linear regression yields better results - it is also far easier for inference purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For more precise predictions, you need to know additionally some more things:

1. Fruit load
2. LAI
3. Ideally - starting weight

Fruit grow out period depends not only on its temperature, but also on its sink strength - as more cucumbers you have on a plant as slower they will grow, and the smallest fruits will get aborted, causing fluctuating yield pattern afterwards. You will see it as a lower average yield without well-expressed fluctuation due big numbers of individual plants with different fluctuation pattern, but if you will start to look at each individual plant you will see individual fluctuations

According to our studies in 2014 - 2017 in University of Life Sciences in Warsaw, cucumber fruit have an exponential growth pattern, and at the fully balanced plant, with a 14-day fruit grow-out period from anthesis, fruit fresh weight gain per day is [% fresh weight gain from final fruit weight (220g)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x55HT.png)

So what would I do -

1. I would build prediction not on fresh weight, but on dry weight
2. I would use fruit count and average fruit age per plant or m2 as a starting point to calculate its sink/energy demand
3. then from LAI I would calculate light assimilation coefficient
4. then from transpiration and CO2 concentration and light sum I would calculate assimilate pool
5. I would distribute assimilate pool over present organs
6. I would recalculate state of each organ
7. For each day - same over and over again

What you can do - from given chart you can get an approximation, what part of energy fruit is pulling from each day, and build a model based on that.

My judgement is, that without knowing plant registration, you will be unable to get to 75% correct prediction, as even in our case with full plant registration and IoT sensors, we are getting ~95% accuracy